# Accordion menu with javascript link issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, accordion

I made this list accordion menu in javascript with a tutorial.

as you see  : each main li class "ToggleSubmenu" is transformed to havn't any link anymore but just be a category to hide / show the other sub li.

my question is :
how to have the same effect but have the ToggleSubmenu having a link AND having the show/hide function ?

as you see the return false block the link, but i can't just remove it.

edit : ideally, how to add a class named ".linked" to say "if there is this class .linked, activate a specific link. if not do the same it already is"

Thank you very much for your help.

Benj

```
$(document).ready( function () {
// all the sub menu are hidden
// except "open_at_load" one :
$(".navigation ul.subMenu:not('.open_at_load')").hide();
// we select all the list items with class "toggleSubMenu"

// we replace their span by a link :
$(".navigation li.toggleSubMenu span").each( function () {
    // we stock what is inside the span :
    var TexteSpan = $(this).text();
    $(this).replaceWith('<a href="" title="Afficher le sous-menu">' + TexteSpan + '<\/a>') ;
} ) ;

// we modify the "click" event on the linksin the list items
// wich have the class "toggleSubMenu" :
$(".navigation li.toggleSubMenu > a").click( function () {
    // Si le sub menu was already open, we hide it:
    if ($(this).next("ul.subMenu:visible").length != 0) {
        $(this).next("ul.subMenu").slideUp("normal", function () { $(this).parent().removeClass("open") } );
    }
    // if the sub menu is hidden, we close the other and we show it :
    else {
        $(".navigation ul.subMenu").slideUp("normal", function () { $(this).parent().removeClass("open") });
        $(this).next("ul.subMenu").slideDown("normal", function () { $(this).parent().addClass("open") } );
    }
    // we stop the link :
    return false;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using data attributes. Add a data attribute for every accordion button you want to have a link (ie call it data-linkeaccordion).

Create a specific click handle on every element having this data attr to open a new window , the url being in the data attr value.

This will not mess up with the existing accordion event.

Comment: hello HB, thanks for your help i will search about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this in your function return

```
return $(this).hasClass("linked");
```

Comment: Hello @MOD finally it doesn't worked. I puted 2 classes like this : <li class="toggleSubMenu linked"> and the effects works, but not the link, because i guess, the effects replace the link... any idea ? thank you for your help

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle